# Calculating the time difference between 2 different times in different time zones considering day light

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

Consider I have 2 times which are for different countires:

```
"2013/02/11 13:20:44" (Tehran possibly UTC+3:30 or UTC+2:30 due to day light saving)
"2013/02/11 15:20:44" (Abu Dhabi possibly UTC+4:00 or UTC+3:00 due to day light saving)
```

**Question1:** How can I accurately convert these times `to Utc`?

I want to mention that the day light saving is not a fixed information and may vary time to time and country to country.

For example in 2010 Iran had not day light savings for some political reasons.

**Question2:** Is there some trust-able place or web service with this information?

Comment: You would probably want to have a look at https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: Most of the information you are looking for can be found in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  The short answer is: Use [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), or [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .net application Time Zone information updates with Windows updates, so if you server always have latest updates, you won't have problems with time zones.

And if you need to convert time, you can use `TimeZoneInfo` class:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2005, 6, 1), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Iran Standard Time"), TimeZoneInfo.Utc)
```

And if you need to, you can get AdjestmentRules for time zones:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Iran Standard Time").GetAdjustmentRules();
```

Comment: Yes, upvoted, so if he trusts the time zone info on his local .NET and OS installation, this is the way. Note that there is a method `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` as well.

Comment: Does it consider the day light savings too? What if we can't trust on OS?

Comment: @mehrandvd Yes, it knows about day light savings. Well, if you can't trust OS. You will have to find another timezone info provider(here i can't advise), or create you own time zones for countries you need

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/)

More detailed information can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I was only really answering Question 2, I don't have much experience with .net, thought this may be more useful than leaving them completely in the dark, every little helps.